# ftp n_list doesnt work with directory with separate words

Tags: php, jquery, ftp

Hi i have this AJAX call:

```
listCall = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "ftpFunction.php",
                data: {"request":"list","path":path},
                dataType: "text",
                cache: 'false',
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $(".fileContainer").append("<p id='waiting' style='margin-left:45%; margin-top:20%;'>" + waitingText + "</p>");
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $("p#waiting").remove();
                    $(".fileContainer").append("<form action='/file-upload' class='dropzone' id='my-awesome-dropzone'></form>");
                    $(".fileContainer").append(response); 
                }
         });
```

and this PHP code:

```
$path = $_POST["path"];
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $path);
.
.
.
echo $resultString
```

When i try to list the file of a directory with a single word as folder name (e.g "testFolder") i can list his file, but if i try to open a folder with two or more words(e.g "test folder") the php return nothing as result string.
Why?

This is a log file of cmd ftp that prove that i can access to the directory:

```
ftp> cd "Ftp test" 
250 OK. Current directory is /test/Ftp test 
ftp> ls 
200 PORT command successful 
150 Connecting to port 50714 
Cattura27.PNG 
Query.txt 
indirizzi per davide.csv 
226 3 matches total ftp: 55 bytes received in 0.01secondi 11.00Kbyte/sec)     
ftp> –
```

Comment: Check your AJAX request and the contents of `$path`. It's pobably escaped (eg. using `%20` instead of spaces).

Comment: If it is not escaped, show us log file of any FTP client (e.g. WinSCP) proving that it's even possible to list that directory.

Comment: you may need urldecode - http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: i try to use urldecode but it doesnt work anyway

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i have posted the log

Comment: Log file, not console output. We need FTP session transcript. Do you have access to server side log? Can you show us server log for the PHP session?

Comment: `data: {"request":"list","path":path},` In case you didn't catch the syntax highligher. You state `path` as a [tag:javascript] variable, which is undefined in your example code.

Comment: @Xorifelse path is a variable passed to the function that contain the AJAX call

Comment: @Interseba5 `listCall` contains the ajax call, which is undefined before `$.ajax()` completes.

Comment: @Xorifelse the function is like that: function(path){ //AJAX call}